# Show number of repetition names ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

So, I have components:

Tracks:

```
render() {

        const tracks = [
         {id: '1', artistName: "Eagles", trackName: "Hotel California"},
         {id: '2', artistName: "Halsey", trackName: "Without Me"},
         {id: '3', artistName: "Ariana Grande", trackName: "thank u, next"}
        ]
        return (
          <div>
              {tracks && tracks.map(track => {
                  return (
                     <TrackSummary track={track} key={track.id} />
                  )
              })}
          </div>
        )
      }
```

TrackSummary:

```
const TrackSummary = ({track}) => {
  return (
    <div>
       <div className="card">
                <h5 className="card-header">
                    <strong>{track.trackName}</strong> by: {' '} {track.artistName}
                </h5>
            </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I want to do is that if `{track.trackName}` is repeated I do not want to display them twice, but only once, with the number of repetitions next to it.
Like here in example:
[image]

I am showing twice `Without Me by: Halsey`. Instead, I would like to show it once and next to show number `2` because track appears twice.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Can you please add your array how it looks like?

Comment: It will print the same value twice only if the value itself is duplicated in the array, so, you need to look on [Filtering Arrays From Duplicates](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-remove-duplicates-array/).

Comment: does `{id: '2', artistName: "Halsey", trackName: "Without Me"}` repeats twice or the `trackName:"Without Me"` repeats?

Comment: {id: '2', artistName: "Halsey", trackName: "Without Me"} repeats twice

Comment: Are you ok to use underscore js?

Comment: @AaminKhan yes, i am ok

Comment: @BartoszTermena: Have added the snippet, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to group by the array using the `trackName`, and then counting how many duplicates we have, and adding it to `count`

```js
var arr = [
         {id: '1', artistName: "Eagles", trackName: "Hotel California"},
         {id: '2', artistName: "Halsey", trackName: "Without Me"},
         {id: '3', artistName: "Ariana Grande", trackName: "thank u, next"},
         {id: '2', artistName: "Halsey", trackName: "Without Me"}
]
        
var grouped = _.groupBy(arr,'trackName');
var mappedArr = [];
_.map(grouped,function(val,key){
  mappedArr.push({
    count: val.length,
    ...val[0]
  })
});
console.log(mappedArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers!